# Excel to voice cells' value whenever it is selected with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm triyin to achieve that Excel "says" the value of a cell when placing on it.

I've got this code but i'm able to hear cells' value only after i select another one. Can you help me?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Set Target = ActiveCell    
    Application.Speech.Speak (Target)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Excel to "say" whatever you enter in a cell, first run this short macro, then make entries:

```
Sub WhatDidYouEnter()
    Application.Speech.SpeakCellOnEnter = True
End Sub
```

and if you want Excel to "say" whatever you have Selected, then the Event Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveCell
        If .Value <> "" Then Application.Speech.Speak (.Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
End Sub
```

Then change it to speak, and not to debug. :)